# Bash unsets *_PID variable before I can wait on coproc

Tags: bash, process

I'm trying to use [coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html#Coprocesses) to pipe the output of asynchronous processes into other shell commands and then check the exit status of the asynchronous process:

```
coproc LS { ls dir; }
while IFS= read i; do echo "$i"; done <&"$LS" # Do something with the output.
wait "$LS_PID"; echo $? # Check exit status.
```

The problem is that the above code does not work, at least not with Bash `4.3.46(1)-release`. After the `while` statement has executed, Bash will unset `$LS_PID` (probably because it notices that the process has terminated). Calling `wait` on the processes still works, e.g.:

```
coproc LS { ls dir; }
P=$LS_PID
while IFS= read i; do echo "$i"; done <&"$LS" # Do something with the output.
wait "$P"; echo $? # Check exit status.
```

This will print `0` or `2` depending on whether the directory exists. Thus it is just an inconvenience that I have to save the PID to another variable. But I'm interested in why this happens and whether I can influence this.

Why is `$LS_PID` unset before I `wait` on the process? Is this behavior documented somewhere? Is there an easy workaround for this, because I think it's a common use case to both use the output of a command and also check its exit code.

Comment: Same behaviour with Bash 4.4.5(1)-release. I can not find this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of the `COPROC_PID` variable, though it's undocumented in the Bash manual.

The correct workaround is to do exactly what you've done; save the value of `$COPROC_PID` in a variable that will not be unset when the co-process exits.

Note that this will *not* work if the co-process exits before you have time to get its PID, so it may be prudent to ensure that your variable has a value before using it.

Reference: http://gnu-bash.2382.n7.nabble.com/Several-issues-with-coprocesses-regarding-exit-status-td11125.html

Comment: Or use `$!` instead of `$LS_PID` which doesn't have the problem. Note that it's the same with the `$LS` variable. Probably better to give up on coprocs in bash or use a shell with a proper coproc implementation, or avoids coproc altogether as most often there's a better way to do things.  See [How do you use the command coproc in Bash?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/86372)

Comment: Looking at that thread Chet Ramey says "I will look at saving the coprocess pids in the shell's list of exited background jobs"; any idea if that's been implemented?

Comment: `$LS` (the stdout of the co-process; some might recognize it as `${COPROC[0]}`) has exactly the same issue; it's concurrently unset when the co-process exits. It depends on timing if you run into that. People should be warned to stay away from `coproc`.